# Magento saves product twice

Tags: magento

Magento double saves a product when I follow the [following article](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin.html).

I have added an extra field that allows the customer to link blog posts to a product, but when I put the `$product->save()` there, it double saves a product. And this results in double images when you add images at the same time (or you create a new product)

Edit:

Below is the code where it saves

```
public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
if (!self::$_singletonFlag) {
    self::$_singletonFlag = true;

    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    try {
        /**
         * Perform any actions you want here
         *
         */


        $customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('blogIDs');

        if(!empty($customFieldValue)){$blogIds = implode(',', @$customFieldValue);}

            if(!empty($blogIds)) { $product->setBlogids($blogIds);                } else { $product->setBlogids('0'); }    
        /**
         * Uncomment the line below to save the product
         *
         */
       // $product->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

And in the config.xml

```
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <pmit_save_product_data>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>blogextend/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                </pmit_save_product_data>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `catalog_product_save_before` event. And in your observer, you should just set the value, without saving product.

Comment: Could you let me know how? Let me know if you need any code. I changed catalog_product_save_after to catalog_product_save_before in my config.xml but it still doesn't work, and it doesn't save the tab's values :)

Comment: What exactly do you want to save?

Comment: I have added an extra tab that allows the customer to link blog posts to a product (it saves the IDs to an attribute). So when removing $product->save(), it doesn't save these values anymore from this tab. And the extra tab is required in the product edit view.

Comment: Make sure, that $customFieldValue is not empty and your attribute name is 'blogids'.

Comment: Hi Roman snitko,
I have add custome tab in product edit but my custom field value not save.
i have used both methods catalog_product_save_after and catalog_product_save_before

My observer  code here:
 $customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('custom_field');
                
    $product->setCustomField($customFieldValue);
Note: custom_field is not product attribute.
I have used  custom tab template
<div class="input-field">
 <label for="custom_field">Custom Field</label>
 <input type="text" class="input-text" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" />
</div>

Comment: custom_field should be product attribute.